# How do I check whether and Android device supports Dolby Digital?

Tags: android, android-tv

Is there an API on android to check if a device supports `DolbyDigtal(AC3)`?

Is there any other way, besides using `AudioManager.getReportedSurroundFormats()` (which isn't listed in the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager#public-methods)?

Comment: What's the problem with `mAudioManager.getReportedSurroundFormats()`?

Comment: @Braiam it looks like [getReportedSurroundFormats()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager#public-methods) is a hidden API that isn't in the official documentation.

Comment: Thank you for answer.
Even if the audio format is none on a TV that supports dolby digital, I want to know if the TV supports dolby digital.
(If the audio format is none, AudioManager.getReportedSurroundFormats() cannot be used to check if the device supports dolby digital.)

Answer (score 0):

Refer to documentation that audio format for Dolby Digital is [AudioFormat.ENCODING_AC3](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioFormat#ENCODING_AC3). So you can check Dolby Digital supported from available audio output in your device like this.

```kotlin
val audioManager: AudioManager = /* ... */
val audioDeviceInfos = audioManager.getDevices(AudioManager.GET_DEVICES_OUTPUTS)
    .filter { it.encodings.contains(AudioFormat.ENCODING_AC3) }
```